# how to make fixed divs in bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I need CSS code like on the below picture :

[image]

, for bootstrap 3.

This colums will be inside `col-md-9`. I did it myself, but when screen size changes it doesn't look good. I am not a professional, please help.

Comment: Add a jsBin of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You have classes for different screen-sizes which work using media-queries.

You can simply use them in any element by defining all classes that you want to apply to the element!

For example to define a container to deal with different sizes, just do it like that:

This example will display the div with width about 9, 6 or 3 cols, depending on screen size: (Using size classes md, sm, and xs)

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
    My content
</div>
```

Comment: I understand. But i want to learn, do i need to create this divs my self or do i need to use inside of col-md-9  like ( col-md-8 plus col-md-4 ) ?

Comment: Create them yourself, bootstrap is just listening on classes you apply on containers.

It is important to know how the gridsystem works in bootstrap.
You have always 12 cols in every row.

If you put a div inside of another div, for example like <div class="col-md-6"> and then add <div class="col-md-3">Content</div></div> The first div will have a viewport of 6 cols in the grid. Next the child div will take 3 cols inside the max width of the parent which already have 6 cols from its parent aswell.

So you split your space in table rows, a child table will split this space into smaller cols.

Comment: Thank you. Actually a working simple css would be great because i am just beginer and really dont know how to order those divs like that.

Comment: @user3034335 In TB when you define row it's width equal to  12 columns. When you define column 9 then it's put  9 column + three column space in right. if you make the column9 again inside column 9 then it will take column 9 percentwise from the parent column9.If you want to broke this responsive then simply gave a container or row div a fixed width so it will do responsive.